# Extracting the part of the string

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping the classifieds site and have difficulty over some part of the string.

the website has ads in mixed currencies, USD and EURO. I'm exporting the some data in csv format. it was good so far untill I saw this:

```
<b>400.00 USD</b>
```

now next ad:

```
<b>237.00 euro</b>
```

and another one:

```
<b>120.00 $</b>
```

and so on.

this is the actual xpath that works:

```
item["unitPrice"] = t.xpath('//span[@style="color:red;"]/text()').extract()
```

and the returned result in csv is `400.00 USD`.
what I want to do is to extract the first part of the string, which is 400.00 or 237.00 and put them under the Price column, and also extract the second part of the string which is either USD or $ or Euro. As far as I understand it will be the same xpath with different regex. What would you recommend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `([0-9\.]+)\s+(.*)$` regex to parse the price, example:

```
>>> import re
>>> prices = ['400.00 USD', '120.00 $', '237.00 euro']
>>> template = re.compile('^([0-9\.]+)\s+(.*)$')
>>> for price in prices:
...     print template.findall(price)
... 
[('400.00', 'USD')]
[('120.00', '$')]
[('237.00', 'euro')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Prices can be many, at least 30 per page.

Comment: @LexStart you can adapt the code I've provided anyway. Or,could you provide the link, so I can see it?